# How to login quickly when there's a very large database?

Tags: performance, authentication

I was always wondering how does the login operation performs so quickly when I'm trying to login my Gmail or Facebook etc. What I mean is that, Google for example, has more thatn million servers, and it takes me nearly 2-3 second to login. I'm not doing anything with that large data now, but I may be later, so I'd like to reveal the technique now when I have time.

Please read the following so I know wherether my theory is right (at least part of it).
My thoughts where that servers are located all over the countries. Lets say 100 servers are in UK. When I'm trying to login, it just knows where I am and passes my username and password to those servers. The  first server to find me in the database will respond.

This methods cuts off a large amount of data to be checked. But what when I move to USA for example, how it'll know where to search first? ...and how does servers deal with thousands of users logging at he same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google replicates data almost to all datacentres across the globe. This is the main reason for Google's speed. If you move to USA from UK, the data would not be already available at US. As soon as you login for the first time in US, the nearest server will be invoked which in turn finds the login history and replicates all the user data from the UK servers.

Note:Like yours, even mine is a theory not proved because Google never discloses these mechanisms

Comment: A following question is how do they handle invalidating the old password when changed. I suppose a password change could be a background process with an acceptable little delay on some servers where they tell every 'local' node globally that the old password is now invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how they actually do it, but there are plenty of techniques for spreading the load. One particularly easy solution is to use a hash of your username to locate the partition that holds your credentials.

If you want to geo-locate the auth server, you can look up the origin IP in a GeoIP database like MaxMind's. When a local server is found, if it doesn't have the user's creds, it can do a one-off slow fetch from a central farm.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo's partitioning is correct.  Most modern large databases support splitting the data in such a way.

To answer the other bit of your question, your data could be replicated to multiple physical locations by default anyway for redundancy.  Using geo-lookups on your IP can hint about which servers are closest to send the query to.  Or you can use a map-reduce type of solution - send the job to a few servers, and just take the answer that arrives back first.

Ensuring your query is satisfied from RAM (via caching) instead of from the disk where the db is persisted, tends to have a dramatic effect.